# How to rebuild Lucene Index using API?

Tags: content-search, sitecore-api

We have to rebuild Lucene index on our CD server. 

 Is there any Sitecore API to rebuild Lucene index? or rebuild a portion of tree items?

Comment: do you have a specific requirement to have to manually trigger the reindex on a CD node? 
You can configure your indexing strategies to have Sitecore rebuild those for you without the need of a manual intervention. For example when publishing a item to rebuild the indexes... You can check more about this here
https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/indexing/index_update_strategies

Comment: we have configured `publishAsync` strategy in configuration. Sometimes if we rebuild the index it solve the problem .  if we feel some specific items are not coming in this we will rebuild specific item only.

Comment: Are you seeing any errors on logs? If you address the cause of why some items are going through and others not you probably don't need to manually rebuild the indexes.

Comment: I am very much sure if you have configure indexing strategies properly, you don't need to think in API way to rebuild Lucene. As Diego suggest you should try to address the cause, unless there any specific requirement.

Comment: Rebuilding the index with is a another backup plan if anything happens wrong.

Comment: As @Diego pointed out- whenever I've had issues with indexing, if I clean up any errors in logs (due to computed fields, missing languages, etc.) the issues are fixed. Even when the error messages have nothing to do with the problem, it's good to clean then up.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should have a look at the documentation form Sitecore:

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/80/setting_up_and_maintaining/search_and_indexing/indexing/rebuild_search_indexes

You can rebuild indexes from custom code by using this:

```
// To rebuild "new" search indexes, use this piece of code for every "new" index    
IndexCustodian.FullRebuild(ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("[INDEX NAME]"), true);
```

To rebuild all indexes:

```
// Or to rebuild all indexes, use the following piece of code:
IndexCustodian.RebuildAll();
```

If you would like to index a single item:

```
IndexCustodian.Refresh(ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("[INDEX NAME]"), itemToRefresh);
```

If you need to index a tree:

```
SitecoreIndexableItem indexableFolder = new SitecoreIndexableItem(item);     
IndexCustodian.RefreshTree(indexableFolder);
```

Comment: is there any option to rebuild some items or portion of tree items?

Comment: I have added a code snippet for refresh tree aswell. Hopefully it will help you.

Comment: we will try with this, hope it may solve the problem.